# How to filter a pivot table by color in Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, colorfilter

**Problem:** It´s not very clear, how to color filter the data in pivot table in excel. Your pivot table probably looks something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: add some random sell near the pivot table and add filters to it. Exaample:

[image]